# RecyclerView.Adapter onClick

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am having trouble implementing `view.OnClickListener` in my `RecyclerView.Adapter`. I am trying to implement multi-pane layout (landscape tablet layout version with `RecyclerView` and detail side by side). I have so far created this `Activity`:

```
public class MovieListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        MovieListFragment movieListFragment = new MovieListFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.recycler_view_fragment, movieListFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.commit();

    }

}
```

which starts a `Fragment`:

```
public class MovieListFragment extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private MoviesAdapter mAdapter;

    public MovieListFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(getContext());

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie_list, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getPopularMovies();
    }

    private void getPopularMovies() {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("http://api.themoviedb.org")
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build();
        MoviesApiService service = restAdapter.create(MoviesApiService.class);
        service.getPopularMovies(new Callback<Movie.MovieResult>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Movie.MovieResult movieResult, Response response) {
                mAdapter.setMovieList(movieResult.getResults());
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) { error.printStackTrace(); }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

}
```

which calls the `RecyclerView.Adapter`:

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieViewHolder>  {

    private List<Movie> mMovieList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context mContext;

    public MoviesAdapter(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); //
    }

    @Override
    public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_row_item, parent, false);
        final MovieViewHolder viewHolder = new MovieViewHolder(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MovieDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(MovieDetailActivity.MOVIE_EXTRA, mMovieList.get(position));
                mContext.startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Movie movie = mMovieList.get(position);
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(movie.getPoster())
                .placeholder(R.color.colorAccent)
                .into(holder.thumbnail);
        holder.movieTitle.setText(movie.getTitle());
        holder.rating.setText(movie.getRating());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (mMovieList == null) ? 0 : mMovieList.size();
    }

    public void setMovieList(List<Movie> movieList) {
        this.mMovieList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.mMovieList.addAll(movieList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Here in `onClick` I need to decide whether to start a new `Activity` (like in my code) or update content of detail `Fragment` (in my tablet landscape layout).
According to [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html), you should decide based on fact if your DetailFragment is != null in activity like this:

```
public void onItemSelected(int position) {
        DisplayFragment displayFrag = (DisplayFragment) getFragmentManager()
                                    .findFragmentById(R.id.display_frag);
        if (displayFrag == null) {
            // DisplayFragment (Fragment B) is not in the layout (handset layout), 
            // so start DisplayActivity (Activity B) 
            // and pass it the info about the selected item 
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else { 
            // DisplayFragment (Fragment B) is in the layout (tablet layout), 
            // so tell the fragment to update 
            displayFrag.updateContent(position);
        } 
    }
```

But I'm not able to check this in Adapter. Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created the custom interface click action to get the control in fragment class

i hope it will works for you

public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter  {

```
MoviesAdapterCallback moviesAdapterCallback;
private List<Movie> mMovieList;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context mContext;

public MoviesAdapter(Context context,MoviesAdapterCallback moviesAdapterCallback) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.moviesAdapterCallback =moviesAdapterCallback;
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); //
}

@Override
public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_row_item, parent, false);
    final MovieViewHolder viewHolder = new MovieViewHolder(view);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           /* int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MovieDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MovieDetailActivity.MOVIE_EXTRA, mMovieList.get(position));
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

*/            moviesAdapterCallback.MovieClicked(view);

```
        }
    });
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Movie movie = mMovieList.get(position);
    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(movie.getPoster())
            .placeholder(R.color.colorAccent)
            .into(holder.thumbnail);
    holder.movieTitle.setText(movie.getTitle());
    holder.rating.setText(movie.getRating());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (mMovieList == null) ? 0 : mMovieList.size();
}

public void setMovieList(List<Movie> movieList) {
    this.mMovieList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.mMovieList.addAll(movieList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public interface MoviesAdapterCallback {
    void MovieClicked(View view);
}
```

}

in Fragment Class

public class MovieListFragment extends Fragment {

```
@BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private MoviesAdapter mAdapter;

public MovieListFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie_list, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(getContext(), new MoviesAdapter.MoviesAdapterCallback(){
        @Override
        public void MovieClicked(View view) {
            DisplayFragment displayFrag = (DisplayFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.display_frag);
            if (displayFrag == null) {
                // DisplayFragment (Fragment B) is not in the layout (handset layout),
                // so start DisplayActivity (Activity B)
                // and pass it the info about the selected item
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                // DisplayFragment (Fragment B) is in the layout (tablet layout),
                // so tell the fragment to update
                displayFrag.updateContent(position);
            }
        }
    });
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getPopularMovies();
}

private void getPopularMovies() {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("http://api.themoviedb.org")
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();
    MoviesApiService service = restAdapter.create(MoviesApiService.class);
    service.getPopularMovies(new Callback<Movie.MovieResult>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Movie.MovieResult movieResult, Response response) {
            mAdapter.setMovieList(movieResult.getResults());
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) { error.printStackTrace(); }
    });
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you! Works fine now, I just had to change and pass Movie object into Callback instead of View.